# VBScript to start multiple services

Tags: vbscript

I need to start multiple services using a VBScript.
I wrote this script to start the services and when I run it, it doesn't give any errors and it doesn't start the services. Any Ideas where the problem might be ?

```
    sComputer = "."
    aTargetSvcs= Array ("ServiceOne" &_
    "ServiceTwo" &_
    "ServiceThree" &_
    "ServiceFour")
     Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!\\" _
     & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
     Set cServices = oWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service")
     For Each oService In cServices
     For Each sTargetSvc In aTargetSvcs
     If LCase(oService.Name) = LCase(sTargetSvc) Then
     If oService.State = "Stopped" Then
     oService.StartService()
    End If
    End If
    Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I had to use a comma-delimited. Here the change and it works:
However, how can I make each service on its own line to be easy because I have lots of services that I start up. If there is a way to make each service on its own, it would be much easier to read and manage.

```
sComputer = "."
aTargetSvcs= Array ("ServiceOne","ServiceTwo","ServiceThree")
Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!\\" _
  & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set cServices = oWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service")
For Each oService In cServices
 For Each sTargetSvc In aTargetSvcs
  If LCase(oService.Name) = LCase(sTargetSvc) Then

    If oService.State <> "Stopped" Then
      oService.StartService()    
     End If
End if
Next
Next
```

Comment: as you knew how to write a multiline statement (hint: _) when you concatenated the service names into a string, I suspect you are pulling legs.

Comment: I'm really new into scripting and programming in general. I kind of managed to make it work after some research. I will try to make it on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your aTargetSvcs is not what you think it is - an array containing four strings - but:

```
Option Explicit

Dim aTargetSvcs : aTargetSvcs = Array ("ServiceOne" &_
    "ServiceTwo" &_
    "ServiceThree" &_
    "ServiceFour")
WScript.Echo UBound(aTargetSvcs)
WScript.Echo aTargetSvcs(UBound(aTargetSvcs))
```

output:

```
cscript 21036510.vbs
0
ServiceOneServiceTwoServiceThreeServiceFour
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How would I fix this?

Comment: @user3077069 - by creating an array of four elements instead of concatenating (&) four strings into one. You did look at the docs for the Array() function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsxhtazh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)?